# How to get a facet from a std::locale object?

Tags: c++, locale

I want to get the numpunct<char> facet for the native locale.  I can generate a native locale object by constructing an object with an empty string `std::locale native_loc("")`, but once I have it how do I get a `numpunct` from it? The documentation I've found doesn't really show the connection between the two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `use_facet<facet_type>(locale)`:

```
std::numpunct<char> const&n = std::use_facet< std::numpunct<char> >(std::locale(""));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. I missed that when I was looking at the documentation for `<locale>`.

Comment: The returned reference is invalid once the temporary object `std::locale("")` is destroyed.